# Copy and Paste from one workbook into multiple CSV workbooks in a folder

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I am trying to create a macro that from a blank workbook, and another workbook already open titled "data process-extract workbook" that will open all .csv files in a specified folder and run the macro. The issue I am having is part of the macro is to copy a large column of data from "data process-extract workbook" and paste it into the .csv file that the macro will be running in. I am having a problem getting from the copied data back into the file the macro is running in. It appears it has something to do with the "Windows(Mypath & MyFile).Activate" portion. I have tried several different ways to reference back to the currently opened .CSV file but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String

    'Open Files

    MyPath = "C:generic folder"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv")
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
        'Run Macro on CSV files
        'Copy data from template workbook
        Windows("Data process-extract workbook.xlsb").Activate
        Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1:R4000C1"
        Selection.Copy

        'need to figure out how to paste into whatever .csv workbook is currently having the macro run in'
        Windows("=wkb").Activate
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
            , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

        ActiveWorkbook.Close True

        MyFile = Dir

    Loop
End Sub
```

Thank

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the Workbook object that you assigned to be a reference to the CSV file, i.e. change

```
Windows("=wkb").Activate
```

to

```
wkb.Activate
```